# Apple watch app size limit exceeded

Tags: ios, xamarin, watchkit

I am trying put my iOS app (that has an Apple Watch extension) on TestFlight, but I receive this error:

`TestFlight ERROR ITMS-90389: "Size Limit Exceeded. The size of watch application 'myAppName' (78MB) has exceeded the 50MB size limit."`

The watch extension is very minimal and I'm not referencing anything large. I am using Xamarin. Does know a solution for this?

Comment: Do you have the Release build / Linker enabled?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's it. I'll try it and let you know. To be more specific for anyone else, right-click the watch projects (the extension too) -> Options -> watchOS Build -> Linker behavior -> Don't Link

Comment: That didn't work. It actually made it worse for some reason, it jumped to 226MB now...

Comment: I tried setting it to "Link All" and it dropped it 75MB, but it's still too much.

Comment: Some ?s: Which version of `Xamarin.iOS` are you using, which third-party packages are you using, are you including large/numerous BundleResources?....

Comment: I just updated everything on my Mac (Xamarin, Xcode and the OS) and tried it again and it's still 78MB. The only third-party package I'm referencing is Newtonsoft.Json. And I have 2 xcassets (one in the watch project, the other in the watch extension project) that have a total of 10 images, that add up to about 1MB.

Comment: Open the created `.app` (`Show Package Contents` if using Finder), what is the size of the `.appex` file within the Plugin folder(?) vs. the size of the media elements/assets. i.e. Make sure that the images are not expanding from their original size...

Comment: The image sizes in there are ok. Just the executable for the extension project in there is 72MB. A colleague just told me that referencing `Newtonsoft.Json` might cause a problem, so I'm going to remove it and use the default `XmlSerializer` class instead and see if that helps.

Comment: Is there a way to see how large the Watch Extension is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing the `Newtonsoft.Json` library from the watch extension project (I'm using `XmlSerializer` now instead). The watch app diminished to 46MB and can now publish my app on TestFlight.

Answer (score 11):

For those who face 'Size Limit Exceeded' problem and not using Xamarin. Go to the extension's project settings, and set Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries to No.

Comment: Do you know why this works?  This did work for me,  no crashes on the watch even with the "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" set to No. I guessing the extension picks up the standard libraries from the main app, but I have not seen any documentation indication that to be the case.

Comment: I  set Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries to No in ".watchkitapp" target. If I set that to No in ".watchkitapp.watchkitextension", it crashes for missing library.